# dynamic array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

I need to implement a 5x5 dynamic array where 
every element in it is equal to the sum of its two indices. For example, the first element, at (0,0), has the value 0+0=0.

Here is my code:

```
# include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int size =5;
    int *array=new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)



    delete [] array;

  return 0;

}
```

I need help to implement sum of index.

Comment: A 5x5 array should probably have more than 5 elements. I do suggest you use vectors rather than raw pointers.

Comment: @asmaa, the reason the question and the answers are downvoted is because we discourage questions that are probably homework without much evidence that you at least tried to come up with a solution.

Comment: An explanation of *why* a dynamic array is necessary would help to clarify the requirements..  There is no built-in resizable array in `C++`, so if by dynamic one means resizable, this is something that has to be worked around.  As far as merely being able to reference the sum of two indexes, the natural suggestion would be to use a function rather than an array.  In that case the issue of "resizing" is avoided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need at first to implement a two-dimensional array.:)

Here you are.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const size_t N = 5;

    int ( *array )[N] = new int[N][N];

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ ) array[i][j] = i + j;
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ ) std::cout << array[i][j] << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    delete [] array;

    return 0;
}
```

And do not pay attention that the answer is down voted. There is nothing wrong with the answer. :)

Comment: @hardmath The answer is the most helpful. The OP asked how to implement a 5x5 dynamic array and I showed how it can be done. You can describe your own fantasies in your own answer to the question.

Comment: Your code is helpful in constructing and "destructing" a 2D array, and it is "dynamic" to the extent that the array is allocated on the stack with a parameter `N` for size, but this might not be the sense of "dynamic" that the OP has in mind.  I'm not your downvoter, but surely some words of explanation for your code would improve the answer, and almost as surely earn my upvote :) !

Comment: @hardmath Once again write your own answer. What is the matter?

Comment: thank you all very much you hve helped me and your explanation is wonderfull, now i get it :)

Comment: I haven't seen it usually done like this but it's perfectly fine, considering that here the OP really needs a 2D array (so each col dimension is the same).

Comment: @hardmath The array is not allocated on the stack. Here you have a pointer to array-N, `int ( *array )[N]`, and you allocate memory for it on the free store. In other words, you allocate space for `N` such arrays, and your pointer-to-array points to the first element (which is what you call the first row).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should create a 2d-array, not just a array.

```
void foo() {
  int **a = new int*[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        a[i] = new int[5];
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
     for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        a[i][j] = i + j;
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
           cout << a[i][j] << " ";
      cout << endl;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
     delete[] a[i];
  delete[] a;
}
```

And, of course, don't forget to clear your memory)

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please provide both code and explanations that address the OP's problem.

Comment: This is horrible to read and maintain. There are faster and easier ways to implement 2d arrays.